# PHP sessions giving error

Tags: php, session

This code gives me an error in my web browser. Please help me

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['user_name']=$_POST['user_input']
?>

<html>
    <body>
        <form action='session2.php' method='POST'>
        <b>Username : <b><input type='text' name='user_input'>
        <input type='submit' value='login'>
        </form>
    </body>  
</html>
```

Comment: Where is the error? and btw you are missiong `;` in your `session` line

Comment: `if(isset($_POST['user_input']){  session_start();
    $_SESSION['user_name']=$_POST['user_input'];}` I guess the error occurs on page load (GET request) - you need to check if the data has been posted

Comment: Error reporting is there to help you!

Comment: ... http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a parse error, need a semi-colon at the end of this line:

```
$_SESSION['user_name'] = $_POST['user_input'];
```

Also it's possible you'll get a notice about an undefined variable when you first load the page. You should check for `$_POST` first:

```
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['user_input'])) {
    $_SESSION['user_name'] = $_POST['user_input'];
}
```

Comment: I think you are long enough on SO that you know that there are dupes for this and that there is a close cote -> off topic: This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced **or a simple typographical error**. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. **This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.**

Comment: @Rizier123 And yet, I helped the guy. Is that so wrong? =)

Comment: @Rizier123 Just because you can close an answer doesn't always make it the best solution. Sometimes showing a beginner their error is just a nice thing to do.

Comment: @jszobody I agree with you and I don't want to discuss here, but I think what OP is missing is this: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3933332 Where is the effort? I don't see any effort, research or attempts from OP's side, so I think it's bad if you support questions with no effort. Anyway it's already written

Answer (score 0):

You forget the semi-colon. Use the code below

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['user_name']=$_POST['user_input'];
?>

<html>
    <body>
        <form action='session2.php' method='POST'>
        <b>Username : <b><input type='text' name='user_input'>
        <input type='submit' value='login'>
        </form>
    </body>  
</html>
```

Hope this helps you